# How to let valgrind to report "where" a "definitely lost" happens

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

Is there a way to let valgrind to report "where" a "definitely lost" happens?

What I want is not "where it's allocated", but "where that poor piece of memory got leaked".

For example, this piece of code has a "definitely lost" leak when `f()` returns:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void f () {
    void *ptr = malloc(42);
}

int main () {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

But valgrind only reports the origin of allocation:

```
==9772== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9772==     in use at exit: 42 bytes in 1 blocks
==9772==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 42 bytes allocated
==9772==
==9772== 42 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==9772==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9772==    by 0x40053E: f (test.c:4)
==9772==    by 0x400552: main (test.c:8)
==9772==
==9772== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9772==    definitely lost: 42 bytes in 1 blocks
==9772==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9772==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9772==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9772==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9772==
==9772== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9772== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I'm using `--leak-check=full` and `--track-origins=yes`.

Comment: I start to think it's impossible, or very difficult to implement, if valgrind doesn't track every single instruction. But I'll leave this question open for a while.

Comment: I don't think valgrind can do this, there's some other techniques you might try though: first, there's the boehm garbage collector, which basically works by scanning the program's memory for a pointer address and has a leak detection mode, but since it doesn't run constantly and stack variables don't get overwritten instantly, you'd need to make a function to call after every function with the variable that allocates a large ish array, sets it to zero, and calls the GC.  Alternatively, you could use C++ and use a wrapper pointer class whose destructor and copy operator do leak checking.

Comment: The definition of "lost" is allocated but nothing points to it anymore.  Won't be easy for valgrind to determine exactly when that happens...For followers, `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=definite ./your_binary` may be useful.

Comment: @rogerdpack Yeah, I guess it's like the halting problem, probably there is no general method to detect a memory leak right after it happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I want is not "where it's allocated", but "where that poor piece
>   of memory got leaked".

No, Valgrind only reports where the memory was allocated, but not when how or why it was leaked. This behavior is documented in [Memcheck manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.leaks):

> If --leak-check=full is specified, Memcheck will give details for each
>   definitely lost or possibly lost block, including where it was
>   allocated. (Actually, it merges results for all blocks that have the
>   same leak kind and sufficiently similar stack traces into a single
>   "loss record". The --leak-resolution lets you control the meaning of
>   "sufficiently similar".) It cannot tell you when or how or why the
>   pointer to a leaked block was lost; you have to work that out for
>   yourself.

Also `--track-origins` has nothing to do with memory leaks. It is used for tracking  the origin of uninitialised values.